# Replace text within searched text using sed and awk?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have some text in a file that looks like this:

```
BLAHBLAHBLAH RANDOM DATA
    data = [ 
            #'oink',
            #'bigger oink',
            #'stronger oink',
            #'strongest oink',
            #'beyond godlike oink'
        ]
    BLAHAHAHA RANDOM LASDKFJS DATA
```

I'm trying to remove all the #'s within the data array, in my first attempt I tried this:

```
sed -i "s/#'/'/g" file
```

This worked great - however, it searched outside of the data[] scope.

I then tried to combine awk with sed:

```
awk '/data = \[/,/\]/' file | sed -i "s/# '/'/g"
```

This doesn't work because sed is not getting an input file.

How can I combine these, or how can I do it with one command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
awk '/data = \[/{f=1} f{sub(/#/,"")} /\]/{f=0} 1' file
```

For example, borrowing @anubhava's input and massaging to include a line with a `#` inside the quoted text:

```
$ cat file
# text
BLAHBLAHBLAH RANDOM DATA
    data = [
            #'oink',
            #'bigger oink',
            #'stronger oink',
            #'mother #$^*@ oink',
            #'beyond godlike oink'
        ]
    BLAHAHAHA RANDOM LASDKFJS DATA

            #'stronger oink',
            #'strongest oink',

$ awk '/data = \[/{f=1} f{sub(/#/,"")} /\]/{f=0} 1' file
# text
BLAHBLAHBLAH RANDOM DATA
    data = [
            'oink',
            'bigger oink',
            'stronger oink',
            'mother #$^*@ oink',
            'beyond godlike oink'
        ]
    BLAHAHAHA RANDOM LASDKFJS DATA

            #'stronger oink',
            #'strongest oink',
```

The above will work with any awk on any OS.

Answer (score 1):

Using gnu awk you can do this:

```
cat file

# text
BLAHBLAHBLAH RANDOM DATA
    data = [
            #'oink',
            #'bigger oink',
            #'stronger oink',
            #'strongest oink',
            #'beyond godlike oink'
        ]
    BLAHAHAHA RANDOM LASDKFJS DATA

            #'stronger oink',
            #'strongest oink',

# awk command
awk -v RS='data *= *\\[[^]]*\\]' '{gsub(/#/, "", RT); print $0 RT}' ORS= file

# text    
BLAHBLAHBLAH RANDOM DATA
    data = [
            'oink',
            'bigger oink',
            'stronger oink',
            'strongest oink',
            'beyond godlike oink'
        ]
    BLAHAHAHA RANDOM LASDKFJS DATA

            #'stronger oink',
            #'strongest oink',
            #'beyond godlike oink'
```

Comment: I'm trying to remove only the # symbol, not the entire line.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be doing anything `data = [
   # 'activeCfg',
   # 'cellBroadcastSchedule',
   # 'surveyCfg',
   # 'targetsCfg',
   # 'scheduledOp'
  ]`

Comment: ok try this: `awk -v RS='data *= *\\[[^]]*\\]' '{gsub(/#/, "", RT); print $0 RT}' file`

Comment: Perfect. We have a winner.

Comment: You'll want to set `-v ORS=""` or similar to avoid adding an extra blank line after every match. Also note that this will replace any `#`s inside the quoted strings as well as the ones at the start of each line. Not a trivial thing to fix with this approach if that's an issue.

Comment: Good point @EdMorton, edited. Yes indeed it will remove `#` anywhere between start and end text blocks. I tried to make it safe earlier but it didn't work for all the cases OP had.

Comment: Yeah you need to use match() with it's third arg or gensub() and look for regexps like `(^|\n)\s*#` to replace. Like I mentioned, non-trivial...

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should work, but note it will replace within any block that starts with `data = [` and ends with `]`. You didn't really say whether your data file might have multiple such blocks...

```
awk '/^[ \t]*data = \[[ \t]*$/ { replacing = 1 }
     /^[ \t]*\][ \t]*$/        { replacing = 0 }
     replacing                 { sub("# '\''", "'\''") }
                               { print }
    ' < input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `sed`:

```
sed "/^\s*data = \[/{:loop; /\]/b; n; s/#'/'/g; t loop}" file
```

**Test:**

```
$ sed "/^\s*data = \[/{:loop; /\]/b; n; s/#'/'/g; t loop}" file
BLAHBLAHBLAH RANDOM DATA
    data = [ 
            'oink',
            'bigger oink',
            'stronger oink',
            'strongest oink',
            'beyond godlike oink'
        ]
    BLAHAHAHA RANDOM LASDKFJS DATA
```